# Lodash forEach Associative Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, foreach, lodash

Is there a `forEach` loop in `Lodash` for associative arrays? The function *called* "forEach", I've found, only works for indexed arrays. For example, if I have an array `myArray` with values `[1, 2, 3]`, and do

```
lodash.forEach(myArray, function(index) {
    console.log(index);
});
```

and run the function (in `Node`), I get the expected result:

```
1
2
3
```

However, when I try this with an associative array, it doesn't work:

```
lodash = require('lodash');
myArray = [];
myArray['valOne'] = 1;
myArray['valTwo'] = 2;
myArray['valThree'] = 3;
lodash.forEach(myArray, function(index) {
    console.log('7');
});
```

As you can see from running this in `Node`, the callback function doesn't fire even when it includes something other than the array elements. It just seems to skip the loop entirely.

First of all, why does this happen? Second of all, is there another function included in `Lodash` for this problem, or, if not, is there a way to use the `forEach` function to accomplish this, without changing the original array in the process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Lodash` has the function `forOwn` for this purpose. In the second array, if you do

```
_.forOwn(myArray, function(index) {
    console.log(index);
});
```

you should get the intended result.

I'm still not sure why `forEach` seems to skip the first function, however, but I believe it may have to do with the array not having a "length". A `JavaScript` array's length is the highest numbered index it has. For example, an array `myOtherArray` defined as `myOtherArray[999]="myValue"` will have a length of 1,000 (because arrays are zero-indexed, meaning they start at 0, not 1), even if it has no other values. This means an array with no numbered indexes, or only negative indexes, will not have a `length` attribute. `Lodash` must be picking up on this and not giving the array a `length` attribute, likely to maintain consistency and performance, thus not rendering any output.

Answer (score 6):

```
myArray = [];
myArray['valOne'] = 1;
myArray['valTwo'] = 2;
myArray['valThree'] = 3;
lodash.forEach(myArray, function(index) {
    console.log('7');
});
```

An associative array is just a set of key value pairs, which is nothing but a Javascript object.
Above case - `myArray.length === 0`,
You are just addding properties to the array object, not adding any values to actual array.

Instead initialize your myArray like this and loop through using `forIn`

```
var myArray = {};
myArray['valOne'] = 1;
myArray['valTwo'] = 2;
myArray['valThree'] = 3;

lodash.forIn(myArray, function(value, key) {
    console.log(key + " : " + value); 
});
```

OR just

```
   var  myArray = {
    valOne  : 1,
    valTwo  : 2,
    valThree : 3
   };

   lodash.forIn(myArray, function(value, key) {
        console.log(key + " : " + value); 
    });
```

More about Object as Associative Array [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html)